# Which URL should be in sitemap.xml when redirecting request

Tags: php, seo, sitemap, redirect

Im using Laravel framework to develop my website and I also want to create sitemap. In my controller I'm redirecting 'root' request `http://www.example.com/` to `http://www.example.com/home`. Now which url should be defined in sitemap file?

This...

```
<url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
</url>
```

...or this?

```
<url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/home</loc>
</url>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitemaps (as specified on [sitemaps.org](http://www.sitemaps.org/)) are used "to inform search engines about pages on their sites that are available for crawling".

So always add those (canonical) URLs that search engines may crawl and index.

They can’t crawl `http://www.example.com/`, as it’s no page in the first place, so you should add `http://www.example.com/home`.